# Adding a JavaScript file in a joomla module?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

How is it possible to add a .js file in my joomla module?

The directory structure is like this:

' "modulename"/site/js/thefileIneed.js '

I tried the following, but that doesn't work.

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(dirname(__FILE__). '/site/js/mainscript.js' );
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found this working example in one of our working modules:

```
$document->addScript(JURI::Root(true)."/modules/mod_ourmodule/charts.js");
```

Comment: Are you using Firebug?  It should show you what is trying to be loaded and will, perhaps, give you a little more to go on.

Comment: I am using firebug. It seems as if "JURI::Root(true)" is empty.

Comment: Perhaps a version issue (what are you using), but details about how it SHOULD work, and variations are at http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root

Comment: In firebug, under NET and JS, does it show your file even being tried to be loaded?

Comment: @GregP: is the `(true)` bit necessary? Didn't think it was.

Comment: Defaults to false, here's what the docs say:  If true then only the path to the Joomla site is returned; otherwise the scheme, host and port are prepended to the path. Note that when true the URI returned has a trailing "/", but when false the trailing "/" is omitted.

Comment: Just noticed that it will a double slash in my given example, which is production code - so i guess it doesn't matter on that point.

Comment: ah ok, just that I have always used adding script commands without `(true)` and never had a problem. But thanks for the info above ;)

Comment: Good catch though...presumably Joomla figures out how to deal with the double slash if found, but using it elsewhere, handy to know when/why a slash is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go along the lines of

```
$document->addScript('modules/mod_demo/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
```

for example (this is how I'm doing it in my module) and I haven't found this is an issue, even with joomla being located in a subdomain